# Why am I getting this TypeError? TypeError: object of type 'instancemethod' has no len() [resolved]

Tags: python, python-2.7, email, smtp, smtplib

I am trying to send E-Mails using python, somehow it says: "TypeError: object of type 'instancemethod' has no len()"

I don't understand why this happens, can someone tell me what is going wrong?

device = raspberry pi

Python version = 2.7.16

software = raspbian

E-Mail server = gmail

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart


username = 'MyEmail@gmail.com'
password = 'MyPassword'


def send_mail(text ='email body', subject ='subject' ,from_email = 'My Name <MyEmail@gmail.com>', recievers =None, html =None):
        assert isinstance(recievers, list)


        msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        msg['From'] = from_email
        msg['To'] = recievers
        msg['Subject'] = subject

        txt_part = MIMEText(text, 'tekst')
        msg.attach(txt_part)

        if html != None:
                html_part = MIMEText(html, 'html')
                msg.attach(html_part)


        msg_str = msg.as_string()

        # login to server
        print('initialising.....')
        server = smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp.gmail.com',port=587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        print('logging in.....')
        server.login(username, password)
        
        # sending the email
        print('sending.....')
        server.sendmail(from_email, recievers, msg_str)


        server.quit()
send_mail(recievers=['MyEmail@gmail.com'])

print('done')
```

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 730, in sendmail
    esmtp_opts.append("size=%d" % len(msg))
TypeError: object of type 'instancemethod' has no len()
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Never used any of those modules but please check if `msg.as_string` is a function and if not, you have to call it.

Edit: To add a more thorough explanation, your `sendmail` is trying to check the length of your message, but since you didn't call `msg.as_string`,  it instead has received a method of the instance `msg` of `MIMEText`, which doesn't have a length.